# MonoDroid Displaying database fields with horizontal scrollbar

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have a table with about 20 columns and number of records which will vary from 5-20+.  I want to display all of this data on the screen using horizontal and vertical scrollbars.  I'm torn on what method would be best in order to do this.  I've started on a listview solution but have kind of gotten stuck.  The following is the XML for my layout (ive condensed the table rows but you get the idea)..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnHome"
        style="@style/homeButton"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/btnHomeText"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnHome">
        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/stdWindow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDriverReport"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@color/VeryDarkGray"
                android:text="@string/futureFeatureText"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/OMSGold" />
            <TableLayout
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/summaryTicketNumber"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:id="@+id/textView10" />
                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/summaryDate"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:id="@+id/textView11" />
                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/summaryTruckNumber"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:id="@+id/textView12" />
                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/summaryBeginOdometer"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:id="@+id/textView21" />
                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/summaryEndOdometer"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_column="4"
                        android:id="@+id/textView22" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:id="@+id/tvTicketNumber" />
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:id="@+id/tvSummaryDate" />
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:id="@+id/tvTruckNumber" />
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:id="@+id/tvBeginOdometer" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_column="4"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:id="@+id/tvEndOdometer" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So basically table row 1 is static heading data but every row after that will be dynamically populated from the database, so the number of rows will be variable.

I started on the custom list adapter solution but cant seem to get it working.  Here is my customlistadapter

```
    public class CustomListAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {
        Activity context;

        public List<TicketSummaryMapper> items;

        public CustomListAdapter (Activity context)
            : base()
        {
            this.context = context;
            var db = new SQLiteConnection (db);
            items = db.Query<TicketSummaryMapper> ("select * from mydatabase");

        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            var item = items [position];            


            var view = (convertView ?? 
                context.LayoutInflater.Inflate (
                    Resource.Layout.ticket_summary, 
                    parent, 
                    false)) as LinearLayout;

            //Find references to each subview in the list item's view
            var textTicketNo = view.FindViewById (Resource.Id.tvTicketNumber) as TextView;
            var textSummaryDate = view.FindViewById (Resource.Id.tvSummaryDate) as TextView;
            var textTruckNumber = view.FindViewById (Resource.Id.tvTruckNumber) as TextView;
            var textBeginOdometer = view.FindViewById (Resource.Id.tvBeginOdometer) as TextView;



            //Assign this item's values to the various subviews
            textTicketNo.SetText (item.TicketNumber, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            textSummaryDate.SetText (item.TransDate, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            textTruckNumber.SetText (item.EquipmentNo, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            textBeginOdometer.SetText (item.BeginOdometer, TextView.BufferType.Normal);

            //Finally return the view
            return view;
        }

        public TicketSummaryMapper GetItemAtPosition(int position)
        {
            return items[position];
        }
    }
```

and then finally my activity...

```
[Activity (Label = "AdminActivity")]            
public class AdminActivity : Activity
{
    CustomListAdapter listAdapter;
    public AdminActivity() { }
    public AdminActivity(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(handle,           transfer) { }


    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        //Set the Activity's view to our list layout        
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.customlist);

        //Create our adapter
        listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter (this);

        //Find the listview reference
        var listView = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.listView);

        //Hook up our adapter to our ListView
        listView.Adapter = listAdapter;
    }
    }
```

the customlist layout basically just has a linearlayout followed by a listview and thats it.  thanks for taking the time to look at this...

Comment: Alright the above code is working correctly except its basically recreating the whole xml file I posted on top (repeating for every row) rather then just the rows of data from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with ScrollView setting the horizontal and vertical scroll and inside your main layout

```
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

     .....

</ScrollView>
```